# Getting true in equal() when more characters look like

Tags: c#, string, equals

How to **recognize** two strings when **most characters** are similar

I want get `true` in this samples

```
"Hello Wolrld" == "HelloWorld"
```

OR

```
"hello world!!" == "helloworld"
```

I know that these are **not equal**, But since most of the characters are the same, it is enough for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to say, if  more than `string.Length/2` characters are equal then return `true`?

Comment: Define "most" characters are similar.

Comment: are you mean 50% characters slimier then return true ??

Comment: Yes, but with a lower error rate of 80%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "").ToLower() == your string in lower case
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of the two strings (see for example this [C# implementation](https://gist.github.com/Davidblkx/e12ab0bb2aff7fd8072632b396538560)) and then define a threshold up to which you consider the strings to be "equal".

What a reasonable threshold is depends on your requirements. Probably, defining the predicate as `d <= a * Math.Min(string1.Length, string2.Length)` should work, where `d` is the Levenshtein distance of the strings and `a` is a factor of "similarity" between 0 and 1. In your examples `a==0.3` should work.

Comment: thanks, This is so good and beyond my needs, I used the solution of Jophy job

Comment: If that's sufficient, than it for sure is a good choice: Jophy's solution has a significantly better runtime and memory complexity than the Levenshtein distance. Right tool for the right job. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a very basic check, you can enumerate over the characters using `Zip` to compare them, count the matching letters, and report true if the number of matches are above a certain threshold. This won't capture it if one string is a shifted version of the other; it'll only catch letters in common at the same index.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool FuzzyCompare(this string lhs, string rhs, float ratioRequired)
    {
        var matchingLetters =  lhs.Zip
            ( 
                rhs, 
                (a,b) => a == b ? 1 : 0
            )
            .Sum();
        return (float)matchingLetters / (float)lhs.Length > ratioRequired;
    }
}
```

To compare two strings to see if they match on at least half of the letters, pass a `ratioRequired` of 0.5.

```
    public static void Main()
    {

        var a = "ABCD";
        var b = "ABCDEFGHI";

        Console.WriteLine( a.FuzzyCompare(b, 0.5F) );
    }
```

Output:

```
True
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6safM1)

Comment: Thanks, but it works just until the first character is mistaken

Answer (score 0):

This give true if 80% words are similer **Try this**

```
            String str1 = "Hello world";
            String str2 = "Helloworld!!";

            char[] charArray;

            int per = 0;
            int c = 0;
            if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {

                per = (str1.length() * 80) / 100; // 80% per match logic

                charArray = str1.toCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {

                    String chars = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);

                    if (str2.contains(chars)) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                per = (str1.length() * 80) / 100; // 80% per match logic

                charArray = str2.toCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {

                    String chars = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);

                    if (str1.contains(chars)) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (c >= per) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "true", 0).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false", 0).show();
            }
```

Comment: it's good , but this will recognize  `str1=Hello world!!` and `str2=allow lower` as true too, I want this to pick up typos or mis spelled words.